# handle observableArrayList from model to controller

Tags: model-view-controller, tableview, javafx-8

I'm a beginner and don't succeed to apply solution found on web into my application structure. This is my first post so please be lenient.
I had a Factory/DAO/Singleton template to connect the database.
It works fine even if I've just implement the find function at the moment.

Then, I would like to implement a MVC pattern.
Model is for example the class named "Fichier". This class was used by FichierSQL in order to populate instances of "Fichier".
View is provide by the FXML file named "FenFichier".
Controller is the classe named "FenFichierController".
Another class manage the different views and is named "LoginManager".
EDIT : thanks @Jewelsea for github code about [loginsession](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4631319)

As it's in FichierSQL where the database queries are, I think that it should be here the best place to implement the observableArrayList.
**Problem is** that a cannot access to the "getFichierList" method of this class from the controller to populate the TableView.
**Your comments** are also welcome about the LoginManager class because I will have a lot of windows to manage and I don't know how to do that in a perfect way. Please tell me if you need more snippets.

**Fichier.class**

```
public class Fichier {
private final IntegerProperty fichierID;
/** nom du fichier de mesure */
private final StringProperty nomFichier;
/** le fichier est-il un essai = 1 ? ou un OF = 0 (default) */
private final BooleanProperty isEssai;
/** date de création du fichier de mesure */
private final ObjectProperty<Date> dateCreation;
/** nom du client */
private final StringProperty client;

private static Date DATE_NULL = new Date(0);

/** création d'un fichier vide */
public Fichier() {
    this(0,null,false,DATE_NULL,null);
}

/** création d'un fichier de mesure
* @param fid identification unique du fichier dans la BDD
* @param fichier nom du fichier de mesure
* @param ess essai = 1 ou OF = 0
* @param dtecreation date de création du fichier de mesure
* @param cli nom du client
*/
public Fichier(int fid, String fichier, Boolean ess, Date dtecreation, String cli ) {
    this.fichierID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(fid);
    this.nomFichier = new SimpleStringProperty(fichier);
    this.isEssai = new SimpleBooleanProperty(ess);
    this.dateCreation = new SimpleObjectProperty<Date>(dtecreation);
    this.client = new SimpleStringProperty(cli);
}
/**
 * renvoie le numéro unique de fichier
 * @return fichierID
 */
public int getFichierID() {
    return fichierID.get();
}   
public IntegerProperty fichierIDProperty() {
    return fichierID;
}
/**
 *  renvoie le nom du fichier de mesure
 * @return nomFichier
 */
public String getNomFichier() {
    return nomFichier.get();
}
/**
 * modifie le nom du fichier de mesure
 * @param newFichier
 */
public void setNomFichier(String newFichier) {
    this.nomFichier.set(newFichier);
}
public StringProperty nomFichierProperty() {
    return nomFichier;
}
/**
 * renvoie si le fichier de mesure est un essai = True ou OF = False
 * @return isEssai
 */
public Boolean getIsEssai() {
    return isEssai.get();
}
/**
 * modifie le type de fichier de mesure en essai = True ou OF = False
 * @param newIsEssai
 */
public void setIsEssai(Boolean newIsEssai) {
    this.isEssai.set(newIsEssai);
}
public BooleanProperty isEssaiProperty() {
    return isEssai;
}
/**
 * renvoie la date de creation du fichier de mesure
 * @return dateCreation 
 */
public Date getDateCreation() {
    return dateCreation.get();
}
/**
 * modifie la date de creation du fichier de mesure 
 * @param newDateCreation 
 */
public void setDateCreation(Date newDateCreation) {
    this.dateCreation.set(newDateCreation);
}
public ObjectProperty<Date> dateCreationProperty() {
    return dateCreation;
}
/**
 * renvoie le client
 * @return client 
 */
public String getClient() {
    return client.get();
}
/**
 * modifie le client 
 * @param newClient 
 */
public void setClient(String newClient) {
    this.client.set(newClient);
}
public StringProperty nomClientProperty() {
    return client;
}
```

**FichierSQL.class**

```
public class FichierSQL extends DAO<Fichier> {

private ObservableList<Fichier> fichierList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public FichierSQL(Connection conn) {
    super(conn);
}

public boolean create(Fichier obj) {
    return false;
}

public boolean delete(Fichier obj) {
    return false;
}

public boolean update(Fichier obj) {
    return false;
}

public Fichier find(String nomFichier) {
    Fichier fich = new Fichier();
    try {
        ResultSet result = this.connect
                .createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
                .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_fichier WHERE fichier LIKE '" + nomFichier + "'");
        while (result.next())
            fich = new Fichier(
                    result.getInt("fichierid"),
                    result.getString("fichier"),
                    result.getBoolean("isEssai"),
                    result.getDate("datecreation"),
                    result.getString("client")
                    );
            fichierList.add(fich);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fich;
}
public ObservableList<Fichier> getFichierList() {
    return fichierList;
}
```

**LoginManager.class**

```
public class LoginManager {
private Scene scene;
private Stage stage;

private BorderPane fenMainLayout;

public LoginManager(Stage stage, Scene scene) {
    this.scene = scene;
    this.stage = stage;
}

/**
 * Callback method invoked to notify that a user has been authenticated.
 * Will show the main application screen.
 */
public void authenticated(String sessionID) {
    showMainView(sessionID);
}

/**
 * Callback method invoked to notify that a user has logged out of the main
 * application. Will show the login application screen.
 */
public void logout() {
    showLoginScreen();
}

public void showLoginScreen() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        scene.setRoot((Parent) loader.load());
        LoginController controller = loader.<LoginController> getController();
        controller.initManager(this);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void showMainView(String sessionID) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/applicationTelabFX/FenMain.fxml"));
        fenMainLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(fenMainLayout);
        stage.setScene(scene);          
        stage.setWidth(800);
        stage.setHeight(600);
        FenMainController controller = loader.<FenMainController> getController();
        controller.initSessionID(this, sessionID);
        stage.setTitle("TestLL");
        stage.show();
        showFichierView();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void showFichierView() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/applicationTelabFX/FenFichier.fxml"));
        AnchorPane fichierView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        fenMainLayout.setCenter(fichierView);
        FenFichierController controller = loader.getController();


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

**FenFichierController.class**

```
public class FenFichierController {
@FXML
private TableView<Fichier> fichierTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Fichier, Integer> fichierIDCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Fichier, String> fichierMesCol;

@FXML
private Label fichierIDLabel;
@FXML
private Label nomFichierLabel;
@FXML
private CheckBox isEssaiCB;
@FXML
private Label dateCreationLabel;
@FXML
private Label clientLabel;

/**
 * The constructor.
 * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
 */
public FenFichierController() { }

/**
 * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
 * after the fxml file has been loaded.
 */
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
    fichierIDCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().fichierIDProperty().asObject());
fichierMesCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nomFichierProperty());
    fichierTable.setItems(getFichierList);
}

public ObservableList<Fichier> fichiersData;

public void creationData(){
    fichiersData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try{  
        AbstractDAOFactory adf = AbstractDAOFactory.getFactory(AbstractDAOFactory.SQLSERVER_DAO_FACTORY);
        DAO<Fichier> fichierDao = adf.getFichierDAO();
        Fichier fich = fichierDao.find("%");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erreur de création des données");            
  }
}
```

}

Comment: @James_D : your alternatively idea is already implemented in an other class like this : public DAO<Fichier> getFichierDAO() { return new fichierSQL(conn);} so I think that I misunderstanding something. Should be DAO<FichierSQL> ???

Comment: I meant change the return type of that method to `FichierSQL`. So then you can just call the existing `getFichierList()` method without changing the API of the abstract DAO class (or casting, which would be ugly).

Comment: some internal classes must modify specfics basic object like "fichier" without users interaction but change need to be visible for users. So, it's why I thank to work with basic. You give me precious help. Thanks a lot. Last comment as I show a warning msg : this is not a chat lol. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not already there, promote the `getFichierList()` method to the `DAO` class (you might want to rename it to something more general, as the `DAO` is independent of the `Fichier` class):

```
public abstract class DAO<T> {

    public abstract ObservableList<T> getFichierList();

    // ...
}
```

Now your `FichierSQL` implementation overrides this:

```
public class FichierSQL extends DAO<Fichier> {

    // ...

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Fichier> getFichierList() {
        return fichierList;
    } 

    // ...
}
```

So now in the controller you can do

```
public void creationData(){
    try{  
        AbstractDAOFactory adf = AbstractDAOFactory.getFactory(AbstractDAOFactory.SQLSERVER_DAO_FACTORY);
        DAO<Fichier> fichierDao = adf.getFichierDAO();
        Fichier fich = fichierDao.find("%");
        fichiersData = fichierDao.getFichierList();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erreur de création des données");            
  }
}
```

Alternatively, of course, just have the return type of `AbstractDAOFactory.getFichierDAO()` be `FichierSQL`, so you can do

```
public void creationData(){
    try{  
        AbstractDAOFactory adf = AbstractDAOFactory.getFactory(AbstractDAOFactory.SQLSERVER_DAO_FACTORY);
        FichierDAO fichierDao = adf.getFichierDAO();
        Fichier fich = fichierDao.find("%");
        fichiersData = fichierDao.getFichierList();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erreur de création des données");            
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice ! with some adjustment in my code, the first solution is OK. Thank u :)

Comment: YW. Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question.

Comment: do u think it could be a problem to have this ObservableList public in the abstract class ?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you made a public field. I just suggested declaring the method there. You would probably want to rename the method `list()` or `getList()` or something (both in the abstract class and in the subclass). The API for your DAO is pretty strange, e.g. the `find()` method potentially finds many objects but returns only the last one (??). I can't really comment on the design because I don't know the rest of the application.

Comment: Yes, your're right ! This is what I called some adjustment ;) only the first object was returned before. Please have a look to my new comment. Another thing strange ! Well, thank u for your answer, it was helpful.

Comment: So, I guess I really don't understand what you are trying to do with the DAO design. Why don't you make `find` return a `List`?